# Выравнивание JSON-содержимого по ключам в Sublime Text

Tags: json, sublime-text, форматирование

Есть json-подобный код, выглядящий так:

```
...
{"bias": 3962, "type": "f", "value": 8.8},
{"bias": 400, "type": "cfH", "value": ["a", 1.1, 4000]},
{"bias": 412, "type": "cf", "value": ["b", 2.2]},
....
```

Хочется сделать автоматическое выравнивание по ключам, примерно так:

```
...
{"bias": 3962, "type": "f",   "value": 8.8},
{"bias": 400,  "type": "cfH", "value": ["a", 1.1, 4000]},
{"bias": 412,  "type": "cf",  "value": ["b", 2.2]},
...
```

Руками делать это каждый раз муторно, когда этих строчек больше сотни. Можно ли это сделать средствами Sublime Text?

---

P.S. Плагин *JSON Reindent* пробовал, он делает немного не то:

```
...
{
      "bias": 344,
      "type": "i",
      "value": 18
 },
 {
      "bias": 348,
      "type": "i",
      "value": 19
 },
 {
      "bias": 352,
      "type": "i",
      "value": 20
 }
...
```

Comment: Т. к. JSON — это часть JavaScript, его можно отформатировать любым JavaScript бьютифаером. Попробуйте [**Code Formatter: Format as JavaScript Syntax**](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter/blob/master/CodeFormatter.sublime-commands#L13-L19). В пакете CodeFormatter [**20 с лишним опций**](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter#javascriptjson) — возможно, получится отформатировать именно так, как Вам необходимо. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую этот пакет.

Comment: Отпишитесь, пожалуйста, помог ли этот пакет в решении Вашей проблемы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте плагин [AlignTab](https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab) для Sublime Text.

Установите его в SublimeText через менеджер пакетов. Далее выделите нужный кусок кода и нажмите **ПКМ > Align by > Spaces**

Пример результата:
[image: Скриншот результата выравнивания]

Comment: Вы дали правильный совет, но неполный. Я дополнил ваш ответ и отметил его правильным. Спасибо.